# Xpath get all children with the given anchor

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I got a XML file which contains a lot of lines like that:

```
<class name="CustomerProfileLite" inList="true" >
    <enum name="Order" takeOtherValuesFromProperties="true">
        <value>None</value>
    </enum>
    <property name="Guid" type="guid" />
    <property name="CreationDate" type="datetime" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="LastUpdateDate" type="datetime" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="Revision" type="int" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="Thumbnail" type="string" convertToRelativePathInDB="true" />
    <property name="UmsJob" type="string" isIndexed="true"/>
    <property name="FirstName" type="string" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="LastName" type="string" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="Address" type="string" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="City" type="string" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="PhoneNumber" type="string" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="CellPhoneNumber" type="string" isIndexed="true" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="Birthdate" type="OptionalDateTime" isInEnum="true" />
    <property name="HasFrames" type="bool" />
    <property name="LatestEquipementHasFarVisionBoxings" type="bool" />
    <property name="LatestEquipementHasFarVisionImages" type="bool" />
    <property name="LatestEquipementHasSplines" type="bool" />
    <property name="LatestEquipementHasIpadMeasure" type="bool" />
    <sattribute name="IsModified" type="bool" />
    <sattribute name="LastModificationDate" type="datetime" />
</class>
```

I need to get the class name and all it's properties. I also need to store all the enum values in a different array.

I've made the following code but I can't make it work properly. I can't get the `property` children and the `enum` list.

```
$this->struct_xml =  simplexml_load_file("assets/archi.xml");
$archi = array();
$types = $this->struct_xml->xpath("type");
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $name = (string) $type['name'];
    $archi[$name] = array();

    if ((bool) $type['isComplexType']) {
        $class = first($this->struct_xml->xpath("class[@name='$name']"));
        if (!$class) throw new Exception("Unknown type found $name !");

        foreach ($class->children('property') as $property) {
            $archi[$name]['children'][] = array(
                'name' => (string) $property['name'],
                'type' => (string) $property['type'],
            );
        }
    }
}

$enums = $this->struct_xml->xpath("enum");
foreach ($enums as $enum) {
    $name = (string) $type['name'];
    $archi[$name] = array();
    foreach ($enum->children() as $value) {
        $archi[$name]['values'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

The line `$class->children('property')` returns an empty `SimpleXMLElement`. Also the line `$this->struct_xml->xpath("enum")` returns a null value whereas it should give me a list of enum.

Could you help me to fix it ?

Comment: `$class->children('property')` should be `$class->property`; `xpath("enum")` should be `xpath("//enum")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The line `$class->children('property')` returns an empty `SimpleXMLElement`

While [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) refers to the children of the current element, its first parameter is to indicate namespace, not tag name.

So `$class->children('property')` means to check for child element in `$class` that *is in namespace `property`*.

You can just use `$class->property` to retrieve a "list" of all `<property>` tag inside that class;

---

> the line `$this->struct_xml->xpath("enum")` returns a null value whereas it should give me a list of enum

[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath) is not like `document.getElementByTagName` in HTML DOM. You have to at least specify that the tag is a child of something. The lazy form would be `xpath("//enum")`.

---

**[Here is a simple demo](http://3v4l.org/k29et)**:

```
$dom=simplexml_load_file("xml");
foreach($dom->xpath("//class") as $class)
{
    echo (string)$class["name"];
    echo "\n";
    foreach($class->property as $property)
    {
        echo (string)$property["name"];
        echo "\t";
        echo (string)$property["type"];
        echo "\n";
    }
}
foreach($dom->xpath("//enum") as $enum)
{
    echo (string)$enum["name"];
    echo "\t";
    echo (string)$enum->value;
}
```

Outputs:

```
CustomerProfileLite
Guid    guid
CreationDate    datetime
LastUpdateDate  datetime
Revision    int
...
Order   None
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of SimpleXML::children is for getting childs with a specific namespace prefix. You have to point directly to the node. For example:

```
$class->property->children()
```

For further informations about namespaces and prefixes look at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code to print your data, and add the conditions in that loop,

```
$this_struct_xml =  simplexml_load_file("archi.xml"); //$this->struct_xml = $struct_xml;
foreach($this_struct_xml->property as $property) { 
    echo "name:".$property->attributes()->name." / ";
    echo "type:".$property->attributes()->type." / ";
    echo "isInEnum:".$property->attributes()->isInEnum." / ";
    echo "isIndexed:".$property->attributes()->isIndexed."<br/>";
}

echo "-------------------------------<br/>";

foreach($this_struct_xml->enum as $enum) { 
    echo "name:".$enum->attributes()->name." / ";
    echo "type:".$enum->attributes()->takeOtherValuesFromProperties." / ";
    echo "Value:".$enum->value."<br/>";
}
```